# RVM, FSEvents, and CarbonCore on OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, sass, fsevents

I'm setting up a project that uses SASS, which uses FSEvents to keep from polling the disk. It seems that this doesn't play nice with RVM, however. That means that when I run `sass --watch` I get this warning:

`Warning: Unable to load CarbonCore. FSEvents will be unavailable.`

I realize that it will still work, but I don't want to be polling my disk constantly. I want to get it working with FSEvents. The best information I could find about this was this thread:

http://groups.google.com/group/compass-users/browse_thread/thread/df7d9d0da9ec1eb1

I reinstalled my RVM Ruby (using 1.9.2) as described by Brandon Mathis and downloaded the linked RubyCocoa. However, I get an error on the first step of installing RubyCocoa:

```
[rvm 1.9.2] ~/Downloads/RubyCocoa-1.0.0 $ ruby install.rb config --build-universal=yes
install.rb: entering config phase...
create ext/rubycocoa/extconf.rb
create framework/GeneratedConfig.xcconfig
create framework/src/objc/Version.h
create tests/Makefile
---> framework
create /Users/xxx/Downloads/RubyCocoa-1.0.0/framework/src/objc/osx_ruby.h ...
config failed
hook /Users/xxx/Downloads/RubyCocoa-1.0.0/framework/post-config.rb failed:
No such file or directory - /Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0/ruby.h
try 'ruby install.rb --help' for usage
```

It looks like the problem stems from this being an older version of RubyCocoa (I notice the missing file has 1.9.1 in the path), but in the Google Groups post, Brandon Mathis says specifically to use the version he links and not the newest one.

Does anyone know how to get this configured, or have a link to a recent, hopefully simpler and clearer guide to getting FSEvents working with RVM?

Versions in question:

- RVM 1.2.0
- Ruby 1.9.2 patch level 136 (installed via RVM)
- Mac OS X 10.6.6
- HAML gem 3.0.25 (SASS is part of HAML)

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wrote FSSM, which is what HAML/SASS/Compass use for their filesystem watching backend. While rubycocoa isn't supported in 1.9.x, the latest git version of FSSM has pretty solid support for rb-fsevent. This library currently has other limitations, like only being able to monitor one path (parent directory is a must here), but I'm working on it. ;)

I'd highly suggest installing rb-fsevent, and then FSSM from github: https://github.com/ttilley/fssm

If you have any problems, please don't hesitate to file an issue in the tracker. FSSM is a currently maintained project, and it was originally written to help Chris Eppstein out with providing watch functionality in compass (which was later adopted in sass itself). Ease of use via these libraries is my absolute top priority.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for letting me know about this! You just stole the check.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a lost battle. You can copy the contents of the include/ruby folder from the Ruby source code to that location /Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0/ which will let you run the config command, but after that you will get a lot of errors on the setup command and you won't be able to install it all. People say RubyCocoa doesn't work with 1.9.2 and I don't know if anyone managed to make it work.

Comment: Hmm... that is not good news, if that's true. It must be possible, though, because autotest/fsevent still works under 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the FSSM method above, to no avail...

Gemfile now has:

```
group :development do
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem 'fssm', :git => 'https://github.com/ttilley/fssm.git'
end
```

which installs:
  fssm (0.2.6.1)
  rb-fsevent (0.4.0)

Still getting this tho:
  Warning: Unable to load CarbonCore. FSEvents will be unavailable.

Anyone have install steps to make FSSM work nicely?

Comment: In my case, I had to gem uninstall haml, then gem install haml, gem install sass, gem install rb-fsevent, gem install fssm and all was well.